# Como criar função para "alterar" e "deletar"?

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Tenho uma tabela onde exibe os "dados" já cadastrados, e pra cada dados tem a opção "editar" e "deletar".

Agora estou na dúvida em como faço para deletar e alterar o dado escolhido. Precisaria de uma página específica para o "alterar" ?

O código para a "inserção" de dados está assim:

```
        public function clientes( array $data )
    {
        if( !empty( $data ) ){

            // Trim all the incoming data:
            $trimmed_data = array_map('trim', $data);



            // escape variables for security
            $nomecliente = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->_con, $trimmed_data['nomecliente'] );
            $cpf = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->_con, $trimmed_data['cpf']);
            $contatocliente = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->_con, $trimmed_data['contatocliente']);
            $ruacliente = mysqli_real_escape_string ($this->_con, $trimmed_data['ruacliente']);
            $numeroendereco = mysqli_real_escape_string ($this->_con, $trimmed_data['numeroendereco']);
            $complementocliente = mysqli_real_escape_string ($this->_con, $trimmed_data['complementocliente']);
            $bairrocliente = mysqli_real_escape_string ($this->_con, $trimmed_data['bairrocliente']);
            $cidadecliente = mysqli_real_escape_string ($this->_con, $trimmed_data['cidadecliente']);



            $query = "INSERT INTO clientes (idClientes, nome, cpf, contato, rua, numeroEndereco, complemento, bairro, cidade)
                VALUES (NULL, '$nomecliente', '$cpf', '$contatocliente', '$ruacliente',
                                                                        '$numeroendereco', '$complementocliente', '$bairrocliente', '$cidadecliente')";
            if(mysqli_query($this->_con, $query)){
                mysqli_close($this->_con);
                return true;
            };
        } else{
            throw new Exception( ERRO );
        }
    }
```

É possível fazer tudo em uma mesma função?

Comment: Olá Anonn, sua pergunta precisa ser mais específica, há dúvidas demais nela, e mais importante, pelas suas dúvidas me parece que você ainda não fez um *CRUD* (inclusão/consulta/atualiza/exclusão) em `php`. Sugiro ver antes alguns exemplos na internet, esse aqui é um : https://github.com/glaucia86/projeto.crud.php
Quanto a suas perguntas, veja o exemplo, acima, e crie uma *function* para cada operação

Comment: Você precisa de uma função igual essa mesmo onde ao inves de fazer INSERT, faça outra ação, como UPDATE e DELETE

Comment: Um `if($_POST['deletar'] { DELETE .....}`  Um `if($_POST['editar'] { UPDATE .....}` não resolveria?

Comment: Ricardo Pontual, as telas já estão feitas, o que falta são as funções para deletar e alterar. O arquivo do link da para abrir sem precisar baixar? 

Leo Caracciolo, isso dentre da mesma função ?